# Mockito verify fluent API

Tags: java, mockito, fluent

I would like to know if there is possibility to verify that fluent API was called. I would like to achieve something like this.

```java
verify(utils).newCharge().withPay().withChargeType("Commission").withAmount(1.1).withCurrency("USD").create();
```

but the code above throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Why are you mocking what looks like an immutable data-holder in the first place? This should not be mocked. Use the real thing.

Comment: Hi Michael, you are almost right, the utils class can create some data classes so yeah, I could use use the real thing but ... This way my test would be dependent on real util class so if that one would not work the tests would fail and that should not be the case really (I want the test to fail only when there is problem with the logic of the tested class), second the class it creates is generated by JAXB and it does not implement equal correctly so I would need to compare the each value of the created class manually, which would make the test more complicated.

Comment: "*This way my test would be dependent on real util class*" It's not an issue. [The Mockito team even advocate for not mocking value objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304193/don-t-mock-value-objects-too-generic-rule-without-explanation).

Comment: "*which would make the test more complicated*" What will make the test more complicated is trying to mock every single fluent method. The syntax you have invented is not valid. The actual code to do what you are asking is possible, but will be 100x uglier and more confusing than verifying field-by-field.

Comment: I agree that in case of simple data object with builder for example I would use the real thing but here I have to use third class utils and also I can not do charge1.equals(charge2) because it will return false even though they have same properties (these classes are generated by JAXB). I  have already solved this but I do not like my solution much. The code of the test looks ok, but the preparation is quite complicated.

Comment: If you need to mock it, move it to a new class which can be injected (and replaced in tests). Of course, this defeats the purpose of the builder pattern somewhat.